# how to send data to different tables in mysql database using one form

Tags: php, mysql

Im creating a college management system . 
So depending on the department and level registered by the student to should go to the required table .
I have 9 tables;
3 business administration table for three levels i.e 100level ,200level, 300level

3 Pharmacy table for three levels i.e 100level ,200level, 300level

3 Computer science table for three levels i.e 100level ,200level, 300level

Comment: unless the data/types you're storing in each of those tables is radically different from the others, you shoul probably have **ONE** table, and put the level/classname into that one table as separate fields.

Comment: @MarcB is right. You should have one table for everything. Still if you want to go through your current structure. You can follow my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should try something before posting question.
You could probably try this logic:

If pharmacy is selected and particular level is selected then in your PHP script,

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['pharmacy']) && $_POST['level']=='100'){
    $data = // Place your data here...
    $table_name = 'pharmacy_100';
}
else if(isset($_POST['pharmacy']) && $_POST['level']=='200'){
    $data = // Place your data here...
    $table_name = 'pharmacy_200';
}
else if(isset($_POST['pharmacy']) && $_POST['level']=='300'){
    $data = // Place your data here...
    $table_name = 'pharmacy_300';
}
// Same for all 3 branches...
?>
```

Now, you will have `$data` variable ready to store in database. By means of SQL connection you can add it in database.